# git merge-file: how to incorporate conflicts into <base-file>?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

The man says:

> `git merge-file` incorporates all changes that lead from the `<base-file>` to
>   `<other-file>` into `<current-file>`.

When incorporating changes into `<current-file>`, I would like to incorporate
changes that conflict in a copy of `<base-file>` (let's name it `<conflict-file>`)
and do not touch `<current-file>` in that case.

That way, I would end with:

- `<new-current-file>` that has incorporated has much changes as possible,
- `<base-file>` and `<conflict-file>` that can be diff (I prefer vertical `vimdiff`)
  to see the conflicting changes that I must manually incorporate into
  `<new-current-file>`.

I that possible?

Comment: maybe a combination of `git merge-file --ours` and `git apply --reject`

Comment: Rather than doing all of this (including the thing you were experimenting with yesterday), I recommend just setting `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3`.  The conflicted changes will now show *all three* inputs in the one file. This doesn't always make it easy, but in my experience, it covers most of the cases where the `<<<<<<< ... >>>>>>>` stuff was unreadable—it goes from unreadable to sensible and easy to merge.

Comment: related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/23047330/5272165

Comment: `diff3` + https://github.com/AndrewRadev/linediff.vim may be very cool (https://github.com/AndrewRadev/linediff.vim/blob/master/doc/linediff.txt#L108)